# Is it possible to use DocumentLink and registerUriHandler when using the remote containers?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I installed [laravel goto config](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ctf0.laravel-goto-config) extension in the remote containers and whenever I click on the link that extension generates and that should jump to another file vscode crashes and restarts

I've created the [github issue](https://github.com/ctf0/laravel-goto-config/issues/5) with the extension creator but author doesn't have any experience with remote extensions. In the github issue I also [linked github repository](https://github.com/ljubadr/laravel-goto-config-remote-container-crash) that you can use to reproduce the issue. Note that instead of

```
./vendor/bin/sail up -d --build
```

you can use

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

to start the containers

Once containers start you can follow the readme or you can directly open example link below that crashes the vscode

```
vscode://ctf0.laravel-goto-config/var/www/html/config/app.php?name
```

File `/var/www/html/config/app.php` exists in the docker container

I don't know too much about developing vscode extensions but I managed to find out that extension uses `DocumentLink` and `registerUriHandler` under the hood to generate the link to the file and to handle incoming links. I even downloaded the extensions and tried to debug the issue, but I only managed to get the debugger and breakpoints working when using vscode directly on the host. Once I connect to remote container debugging doesn't stop on breakpoints anymore and vscode crashes when I use the `vscode://...` link

Is it possible to use `vscode://...` with remote containers to open the files?

EDIT:

I found one example where opening files trough links work. In the file `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json` when I hover on the files in the `"dockerComposeFile": [...]` list I can see the link and when I click on it it will open the file. Hovering on the link shows following value

```
vscode-remote://dev-container+2f55...../<absolute-path-to-file>
```

but this handles link with vscode and not with `registerUriHandler`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to pinpoint the issue. In the extension there was a line

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.openFolder', vscode.Uri.file(path))
```

that was causing vscode to reload even if it's the same folder. This only happened in remote containers

Changing this line to

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.open', vscode.Uri.file(path))
```

solved the issue.

Command `vscode.openFolder` should be changed to `vscode.open`

I found more info about these commands [in the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands)